# Chrome extension installation error message

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I built a small Chrome extension - it shows your IP and geolocation information. 
I tested it several times, packaged it (using Grunt) and uploaded to the Chrome web store.
I verified several time that the resulting zip file contains all the files needed by the app + the manifest.

I then removed my local version, and tried installing from the web store. I keep getting this error, even after refreshing, and restarting the browser several times:

> "There was a problem adding this item to Chrome. Please refresh the
>   page and try again."

[image]

How do I debug/solve this problem?

- The code to my extension is very simple, and is actually open on [GitHub](https://github.com/TravelingTechGuy/myipextension).
- The manifest file is available [here](https://github.com/TravelingTechGuy/myipextension/blob/master/app/manifest.json).
- The extension is available on the Chrome store [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/my-ip/lejbibljgiojigkpkhmdgdhmiaddgidd?hl=en-US&gl=US).

**Update**:

Looking at the JS console, I see an error every time I hit the install button:

> webstorePrivate.beginInstallWithManifest3: Invalid manifest

No further information, and to me the manifest file looks ok (and it works when loaded locally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, took a while, but I found the culprit and fixed it.
I used Yeoman and [Generator-Chrome-Extension](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-chrome-extension) to bootstrap the extension. One of the tasks in the Gruntfile.js reads like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('manifest', function() {
        var manifest = grunt.file.readJSON(yeomanConfig.app + '/manifest.json');
        //manifest.background.scripts = ['scripts/background.js'];
        grunt.file.write(yeomanConfig.dist + '/manifest.json', JSON.stringify(manifest, null, 2));
    });
```

As you can see on the third (commented) line, the task injects a background.js script EVEN if you do not need it. Furthermore if you, like me, use a background **page**, this renders the manifest invalid.

For some reason, it will work locally, just not from the store. Once I commented that line, the manifest is valid, and the extension available.

Comment: I took your code directly and had no problems loading it locally so I tried publishing it to just myself and I have no problems installing it from the store without changing anything but your directories. To be exact I made your `app` directory the root for the extension when I zipped it up.

Comment: Yep, that baffled me as well. If you look at my solution, you'll see that the Gruntfile tempered with the manifest. The good news, is that whoever maintains that generator fixed this already.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I removed:

```
"app": {
    "urls": [
    ],
```

From the Manifest.json file and it works. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I logging in with a [proxy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/browsec/omghfjlpggmjjaagoclmmobgdodcjboh?hl=en) and the problem fixed.

Try a proxy as i guess.

Answer (score 0):

> Please try logging out/signing out of the Web Store and signing back in.

source: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/vFBudQDy5UE